# Convert the program interface to another language interface VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, interface, multilingual, globalization

What is wrong with the code to convert the program interface to another language interface? In Visual Basic .NET (Visual Studio 2019)

```
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub ArButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ArButton.Click
        Languages.changelanguge("ar")
    End Sub
    Private Sub EnButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EnButton.Click
        Languages.changelanguge("en")
    End Sub
End Class

Public Module Languages
    Public Sub changelanguge(ByVal languge As String)
        For Each obj As Control In Form1.Controls
            Dim lang As ComponentResourceManager = New ComponentResourceManager(GetType(Form1))
            lang.ApplyResources(obj, obj.Name, New CultureInfo(languge))
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening when you run the code? I was implementing this recently and the below link assisted a lot.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I was use NET Framework 2 so code not work . now i change it to NET Framework 4.7.2 & code perfect now , thanks